# PHP notify me code?

Tags: php

I created a database called aware and a table called email, the table has a field called email in phpmyadmin. I would like to store the email address once a user types it and clicks on notify me. This is for a website coming soon page.

How do I do this, once i have connected to the database what do I need to do?

This is my code so far, please guide me in the right direction. I am not looking for someone to do this for me.

```
                     <div id="main">
                 <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="details_holder">
                    <div class="main_content">
                   <div class="common_container">
                        <h2>We know its taking a long time but</h2>
                          <h1>SIT TIGHT!</h1>
                           <div class="notify_me">
                         <div class="text_holder">Fill in your e-mail address and we will  let you know when we launch</div>
                <div class="textbox"><input name="" type="text" value="email" /></div>
                 <div class="btn_holder"><input name="" type="submit" value="Notify me!"         /></div>
                  </div>
                     <div class="follow_me">
                <h3>Follow us on </h3>
                <a href=""><img src="images/ico1.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
                 <a href=""><img src="images/ico2.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
                       </div>
                    <br clear="all" />
                </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer"><span>A project by <a href="#"></a></span></div>
            </div>
              </body></html>
               <?php 
            $host="xxxxx";
            $dbs="xxxxxxx";
             $username="xxxxxx";
             $password="xxxxxx";
            $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);


             ?>
```

Comment: If this is your code so far, do yourself a favour and use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_` as they've been deprecated for years and are no longer supported.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . Your title is not convincing at all.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented your code in msyqli. Use it.

Just     `$sql="INSERT INTO email (email) VALUES ('$email')";` does all the work.

Code :

```
 <div id="main">
 <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
 <div class="details_holder">
 <div class="main_content">
 <div class="common_container">
 <h2>We know its taking a long time but</h2>
 <h1>SIT TIGHT!</h1>
 <div class="notify_me">
 <div class="text_holder">Fill in your e-mail address and we will  let you know when we launch</div>
 <div class="textbox"><input name="" type="text" value="email" /></div>
 <div class="btn_holder"><input name="" type="submit" value="Notify me!"/></div>
 </div>
 <div class="follow_me">
            <h3>Follow us on </h3>
            <a href=""><img src="images/ico1.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
             <a href=""><img src="images/ico2.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
                   </div>
                <br clear="all" />
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"><span>A project by <a href="#"></a></span></div>
  </div>
  </body></html>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['add']))
 {
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usernamer","password","your_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$sql="INSERT INTO email (email) VALUES ('$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Email id wasadded";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check "INSERT INTO" Statement here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Your code will probably look something like this if you done it right:

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {
    // INSERT INTO 'your_table' ('column','column') VALUES ('your_field','your_other_field')...
}

?>
```